# Second-order derivative of functions $f \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ where $M $ is a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, homology-cohomology, morse-theory, tangent-spaces

I am starting to read a book in Morse theory and Floer Homology. In the first few pages of morse theory I found a definition of second order derivative for functions $f \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$.

However, I am very confused with it. Here it is:

[image]

IN this case, he defines $X$ and $Y$ to be tangent vectors. BUt, as far as I know a tangent vector is such that it maps elements in $C^\infty(V)$ (here  $V$ is a manifold)  to $\mathbb{R}$. So here the $Y \circ f$ would be a number and does not make sense to me that it is being evaluated in $X$. Or in this case we should take them as vector fields?
I am confused and I hope you can help me here.

Comment: $\tilde{Y}(f)$ is a smooth function on a neighborhood of $x$, it takes a point $p$ and maps it to the real number $\tilde{Y}_p(f)$, where this is the action of the tangent vector $\tilde{Y}_p$ at $p$ on the smooth function $f$ (or rather, the germ at $p$ defined by it). As a smooth function in a neighborhood of $x$, it then makes sense to let the tangent vector $X$ at $x$ act on it.

Comment: Ohhh I see. Sorry, how I missed that. So $\tilde{Y}$ denotes a vector field and $X$ is still a tangent vector. Makes total sense, thanks